# Where to define error codes in MVP design?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvp

I am creating a game in C# based of off a board game and I am trying to follow the MVP design pattern. I haven't started the UI yet but I will likely using WPF at first so I thought the MVP pattern would fit well. As I write the models to control the game I have reached the point where I want to define the error codes for the different actions. I'm running into a problem where some actions could be returning one of a few different errors depending on exactly what about the action went wrong.

My initial thought was to have a secondary project, for ease I'll call it `Utilities`, where I would define all the errors as int constants. Then the project with the model could reference it to pick out the error it needs during the actions, and the presenter could later use `Utilities` to have the same constants for the error so it knows what message to show.

Does this make sense as a scheme for error codes in MVP or WPF? Should the model be returning the error and its's display message at the same time or is determining the message the job of the view/presenter?

Comment: Why do you want to use error codes? Maybe there is something specific about the MVP pattern and error codes that I am not aware of, but in general using error codes as opposed to exceptions will lead to increase in code size and higher bug rate when errors are ignored. As soon as a method can return an error code you will have to check for this error code in all callers in the stack above the method until you know that the error has ben dealt with. And most of the time you deal with errors at the top of your call stack which is exactly the place you should put your exception handlers anyway.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Possibly I wasn't clear in what I meant, or error codes isn't quite the concept I meant. It's not that something went wrong in the method, it's that a player of the game took an invalid action in the game itself and needs to be told what about that action was invalid in case there could be multiple reasons. I want a way to communicate that from the model to the view. To me, exceptions are for coding problems and runtime errors, not to pass something like a validation error.

Comment: OK, but why not introduce an error model that represents an error using a richer model than simply a code? Often a validation error contains more data than simply "the input is invalid" like "the end date is before the start date". And if you errors really only are numbers then you might as well use an enum for it.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Strangely enough, that hadn't occurred to me, but a model for errors does make the most sense. Thanks for pushing me in a better direction.